# GAE Endpoints ProtoRPC log request and response

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, protorpc

For debug needs, I'm interested in being able to print the Headers, Request and Response of my Endpoints API. Obviously, I can print the request and the response explicitly in each Endpoints method that I write, but I want something more infrastructural.

I managed to print the headers by implementing the `initialize_request_state()` function, but I'm struggling with finding a way to do the same for the request and response.